# Redis example for Object type

Tags: java

caller 1.

```
Map<String,List<Order>> map = service.findRestaurant("p2");
```

execting here 2.

```
@Cacheable(value = "CUSTOMERORDER", key = "#customerId" )
public Map<String,List<Order>>findCustomer(String customerId){
    System.out.println("Executing getting method " + ".findCustomer(\"" + customerId + "\")");
    Map<String,List<Order>> map = new HashMap<String,List<Order>>();
    return map;
}
```

How to iterate this and get Order for customer?

Comment: Is customerId the key in the map ?

Comment: You are creating a new map in the method. How will it have any values ?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this. Hope this will help you.

```
Map<String,List<Order>> map = new HashMap<String,List<Order>>();

Map<String,List<Order>> customerOrders = new HashMap<String,List<Order>>();

for (Map.Entry<String,List<Order>> entry:customerOrders.entrySet()){
     if(entry.getKey().equals(customerId)){
           customerOrders.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue()); 
     }
}
```